# Expand menu based on width available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I've been investigating ways of creating a responive menu.

The standard technique would be to use a navicon on smaller devices which would trigger some kind of fly out/drop down menu.

I would like the most common options to show on screen, so I came up with the idea of a nav-bar, consisting of only a few important menu items, which would be visible on smaller devices. This would still need the navicon to display any additional items.

I then came across a menu which fulfills my requirements better in that it is more dynamic. The concept is that the menu grows as the screen size grows, but only displays an option when there is enough screen width to accomodate it fully. The remaining options are tucked beneath a dynamic navicon.

Here is the menu: http://www.money.co.uk/

As you will see changing the screen width changes the available options.

I could produce a semi-dynamic version using my media query breakpoints, but it would be good to be able to create a fully dynamic version. I'm guessing that it uses javascript - but as far as the techinque to be able to determine the available space and the space required, I don't know where to start.

I have some basic js/jquery knowledge, but would appreciate it if anyone could give me some guidance on how to go about approaching this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive menus are nothing, but its just a style manipulation as per screen size. You can go for CSS3 media queries to do it. It has inbuilt functionality to define the screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 912px) and (min-width: 681px)
```

Then, you need to manipulate the stylesheet. This is very common approach. Although, you can go with javascript as well by using window resize events and change your stylesheet accordingly. So whenever you will resize the window it will automatically overwrite the defined stylesheet.

Although, it is not recommended to manage it through javascript as it has lots of code complexity while managing the style. Use CSS media queries.

Hope this helps :)